# how to solve the htaccess redirection problem

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I try to solve following problem :

"Trailing slash - Ending slash redirects not configurate correctly."

for search engine optimization.

how to redirect www.some.domain.com/page/ to www.some.domain.com/page

for example ? Do not vote down !

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the trailing slash using the following `.htaccess` rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```